# Why am I getting extra characters?

Tags: lc3

**Program Description**

I used .BLKW to allocate 20 locations for each character that the user inputs and for now, I just want to display the string the user typed at the first prompt. (This will be a pig latin translator, hence the second prompt; but right now I just want to see if I can print out the user input)

**The Problem**

The problem is that when I run it, I get extra characters at the end.

For example:

```
English Word: apple
Pig-Latin Word: apple
English Word: at
Pig-Latin Word: atple
English Word: set
Pig-Latin Word: setle
```

**My Program**

```
.ORIG x3000
START ST R1,SAVER1
ST R2,SAVER2
ST R3,SAVER3

LD R5,ENTER

REPEAT LEA R0,PROMPT          ; loading the starting address of prompt
PUTS                   ; displays PROMPT on screen


LEA R4,ENGLWORD        ; sets aside memory locations for typed characters
INPUT GETC             ; now that user has typed, read char into R0
ADD R6,R5,R0           ; adds the negative value of the ASCII enter key code to the input character
BRz PIGPROMPT          ; if the sum of the ASCII codes from step before is 0, that means user pressed enter so go to PIGPROMPT
OUT                    ; write char in R0 to console
STR R0,R4,#0           ; store typed character into memory location
ADD R4,R4,#1           ; increment memory location so you write next character to the next location
BRnzp INPUT            ; break no matter what to the INPUT step to receive next typed character

PIGPROMPT LEA R0,PIG             ; loads starting address of pig latin prompt
PUTS                             ; displays pig latin prompt on screen
LEA R0,ENGLWORD
PUTS
BRnzp REPEAT

LD R1,SAVER1           ; restore R1 to original value
LD R2,SAVER2           ; restore R2 to original value
LD R3,SAVER3           ; restore R3 to original value

HALT

SAVER1 .BLKW 1         ; allocates 1 memory location for SAVER1
SAVER2 .BLKW 1         ; allocates 1 memory location for SAVER2
SAVER3 .BLKW 1         ; allocates 1 memory location for SAVER3
ENGLWORD .BLKW #20

ENTER .FILL xFFF6      ; the negative value of the ASCII code for the enter key
NEWLINE .FILL x000A

PROMPT .STRINGZ "\nEnglish Word: "          ; initializes a sequence of stringLength+1 memory locations to hold string
PIG .STRINGZ "\nPig-Latin Word: "
DSR .FILL xFE04                           
DDR .FILL xFE06
KBSR .FILL xFE00
KBDR .FILL xFE02
.END
```

**Attempted Solution**

I was thinking that the problem was that R4 holds the string of the first user input throughout the whole program. So for a solution, I thought about clearing R4 after it is displayed so that it's ready to take the next user input. Does anyone know how I would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is how PUTS works -- it prints all the characters starting at the address in R0 until it reaches a 0 ('\0' not '0').

The first time you run it, the memory will contain ['A','P','P','L','E'], followed by zeroes if you didn't randomize memory contents when you loaded the program.  This means that a PUTS call will return "APPLE".  When you enter the new word, it doesn't clear out that memory, so entering "at" will result in ['A','T','P','L','E'], and your print routine will print "ATPLE".

In order to properly finish the word, you need to add a '\0' (a.k.a. 0) to the element after the last character to print.  In other words, if your memory contains ['A','T','\0','L','E'], your print routine will print "AT".

Comment: Can you take a look at this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708532/why-isnt-my-assembly-program-setting-r1-to-the-correct-value

Answer (score 0):

Aqua's right, the PUTs command is looking for a zero to stop printing characters to the screen. I've added two lines of code just after PIGPROMPT and it seems to be working as intended.

Revised:

```
.ORIG x3000
START ST R1,SAVER1
ST R2,SAVER2
ST R3,SAVER3

LD R5,ENTER

REPEAT LEA R0,PROMPT          ; loading the starting address of prompt
PUTS                   ; displays PROMPT on screen


LEA R4,ENGLWORD        ; sets aside memory locations for typed characters
INPUT GETC             ; now that user has typed, read char into R0
ADD R6,R5,R0           ; adds the negative value of the ASCII enter keycode to the input character
BRz PIGPROMPT          ; if the sum of the ASCII codes from step before is 0, that means user pressed enter so go to PIGPROMPT
OUT                    ; write char in R0 to console
STR R0,R4,#0           ; store typed character into memory location
ADD R4,R4,#1           ; increment memory location so you write next character to the next location
BRnzp INPUT            ; break no matter what to the INPUT step to receive next typed character

PIGPROMPT AND R0, R0, #0    ; clear R0
STR R0,R4,#0                ; store typed character into memory location
LEA R0,PIG                  ; loads starting address of pig latin prompt
PUTS                             ; displays pig latin prompt on screen
LEA R0,ENGLWORD
PUTS
BRnzp REPEAT

LD R1,SAVER1           ; restore R1 to original value
LD R2,SAVER2           ; restore R2 to original value
LD R3,SAVER3           ; restore R3 to original value

HALT

SAVER1 .BLKW 1         ; allocates 1 memory location for SAVER1
SAVER2 .BLKW 1         ; allocates 1 memory location for SAVER2
SAVER3 .BLKW 1         ; allocates 1 memory location for SAVER3
ENGLWORD .BLKW #20

ENTER .FILL xFFF6      ; the negative value of the ASCII code for the enter key
NEWLINE .FILL x000A

PROMPT .STRINGZ "\nEnglish Word: "          ; initializes a sequence of stringLength+1 memory locations to hold string
PIG .STRINGZ "\nPig-Latin Word: "
DSR .FILL xFE04                           
DDR .FILL xFE06
KBSR .FILL xFE00
KBDR .FILL xFE02
.END
```

All I did was store a '0' value at the end of the user's string, that way when PUTs is called it will stop at the zero value.